# How to install LAN driver on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, drivers, lan

Some days ago I have installed Ubuntu 20.04 on my PC. System is working normally, but it doesn't recognize my network adapter, so I have no Internet. I tried to install some drivers with `make` command, but it system said

```
Command 'make' not found, but can be installed with:
sudo apt install make
```

But apt doesn't work because of no Internet. This is a magic loop.

What can be the solution for this issue?

Thanks for answer

Edit: Added screenshot of output of `ip a`

[image: ip a output]

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide the output to `ip a` are you using wireless or a wired connection? If wired do you have a link light?